# ORA-01427 - Need the counts of each value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I get "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row" when I run the following query:

```
select count(*) 
from table1 
where to_char(timestamp,'yyyymmddhh24') = to_char(sysdate-1/24,'yyyymmddhh24') 
  and attribute = (select distinct attribute from table2);
```

I want to get the counts of each value of `attribute` in the specific time frame.

Comment: Use `in` instead of `=`.  Or `= any`.

Comment: Using `in` would give me the total count for all the values of attribute. I want a break down of the count by each value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend writing this as:

```
select count(*)
from table1 t1
where timestamp >= trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH') and
      timestamp < trunc(sysdate, 'HH') and
      exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.attribute = t1.attribute);
```

This formulation makes it easier to use indexes and statistics for optimizing the query.  Also, `select distinct` is not appropriate with `in` (although I think Oracle will optimize away the `distinct`).

EDIT:

You appear to want to aggregate by `attribute` as well:

```
select t1.attribute, count(*)
from table1 t1
where timestamp >= trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH') and
      timestamp < trunc(sysdate, 'HH') and
      exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.attribute = t1.attribute)
group by t1.attribute;
```

Comment: Is there a way to modify this query so that if an attribute doesn't exist for a time period, the query outputs the attribute and its count as 0 instead of not outputting the attribute at all?

Comment: @SomebodyOnEarth . . . Questions should be asked as questions, not in comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a join and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
    count(*) AS Cnt
,   a.attribute
FROM table1 t
JOIN table2 a ON t.attribute=a.attribute
WHERE to_char(t.timestamp,'yyyymmddhh24') = to_char(sysdate-1/24,'yyyymmddhh24')
GROUP BY a.attribute
```

This produces a row for each distinct attribute from `table2`, paired up with the corresponding count from `table1`.